# How to check when administrator rights are being used and by who?

Tags: windows-7, administrator

How to check in windows 7 when administrator rights are being used and by who? Does system even track this?

To clarify my question: I don't want to know who has Administrator rights but when rights were used (by typing password in dialog when elevation of rights is required) and by who.

Comment: What edition of windows are you using? Some versions of windows (especially when it comes to users) have more features than other versions.

Comment: Machine I want to check has Home Premium

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

1. Open the `Computer Management` (open the run box, type `compmgmt.msc` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or press right mouse button over Computer icon and select `Manage`).
2. Select `Local Users and Groups` - `Groups` - `Administrators` (see image below).

[image]

---

You can check this via the command line.

1. Open the Command Prompt.
2. Type `net localgroup Administrators`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Check the list of local groups with localgroup.

```
net localgroup
```

Comment: I can't find `Local Users and Groups`. I run command as Administrator. Does it matter that I'm trying this on computer with Home Premium version?

Comment: I think the OP wants something like a timeline when a user has granted himself admin rights (UAC popup), with date, time and user name

Comment: Yeah, nixda is right.